# Joomla Gzip Compression worked just in Homepage

Tags: .htaccess, gzip, joomla3.0, deflate

in my Joomla3 Website, when I enabled Gzip(from Global config , Cpanel Optimize website , .htaccess) , worked as well but just in one page(Homepage) .
Why does this happen?

php.ini

```
zlib.output_compression = On
zlib.output_compression_level = 9
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-truetype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-otf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-opentype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-woff
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-woff2
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/woff
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/woff2

</IfModule>
## END EXPIRES CACHING - JCH OPTIMIZE
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to look at my security and firewall plugins. Specifically, ModSecurity – an application for Web Hosting Manager that helps prevent attacks on your web server. It is a great firewall application and a must have if you are running WHM in my opinion. Interestingly enough, I noticed that if I disabled the Rules Processing engine compression, would work WITH pretty permalinks. This led me to where the rules came from. Which happens to be Pxysoft Anti Malware, another great plugin which I plan to review later. So I went through the rules directives located in the file modsec2.antimalware.conf (where the rules came from). I started commenting out every option and rule and then toggling the rules engine on and off – one by one. I did this by connecting via SSH. Which if you’re not familiar with, you really should read in-depth tutorials before messing around. Anyways, I came across the option SecDisableBackendCompression On and commented it out. After restarting the rules engine, gzip worked on all URLs! Finally!